# UI5 - Resource not found

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm working with the OpenUI5 tutorial on https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/b4d66ebee72645c1a3501a769e935541.html

Right now at "Step 7" I am getting an error loading the app:

```
failed to load 'sap/m/splitApp.js' from resources/sap/m/splitApp.js: 404 - Resource could not be found!
```

The error message is thrown by UIComponent.js, a file from the UI5 library, which means, that the library itself is found.

Please help.

The code is an exact copy from the tutorial and the project was created by Eclipse and the UI5 plugin.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>

    <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
                "sap.ui.demo.tdg": "./"
            }'>
    </script>
    <!-- only load the mobile lib "sap.m" and the "sap_bluecrystal" theme -->

    <script>
        sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
            new sap.m.Shell({
                app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                    height : "100%",
                    name : "sap.ui.demo.tdg"
                })
            }).placeAt("content");
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
</body>
</html>
```

Component.js

```
jQuery.sap.declare("sap.ui.demo.tdg.Component");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.demo.tdg.MyRouter");

sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("sap.ui.demo.tdg.Component", {
 metadata : {
 name : "TDG Demo App",
 version : "1.0",
 includes : [],
 dependencies : {
  libs : ["sap.m", "sap.ui.layout"],
  components : []
 },
 rootView : "sap.ui.demo.tdg.view.App",
 config : {
  resourceBundle : "i18n/messageBundle.properties",
  serviceConfig : {
   name : "Northwind",
   serviceUrl : "http://services.odata.org/V2/(S(sapuidemotdg))/OData/OData.svc/"
  }
 },
 routing : {
   config : {
    routerClass : sap.ui.demo.tdg.MyRouter,
    viewType : "XML",
    viewPath : "sap.ui.demo.tdg.view",
    targetAggregation : "detailPages",
    clearTarget : false
   },
  routes : [
   {
    pattern : "",
    name : "main",
    view : "Master",
    targetAggregation : "masterPages",
    targetControl : "idAppControll",
    subroutes : [
           {
                                        pattern : "{product}/:tab:",
                                        name : "product",
                                        view : "Detail"
                                    }
                                  ]
                  },
                  {
                      name : "catchallMaster",
                      view : "Master",
                      targetAggregation : "masterPages",
                      targetControl : "idAppControl",
                      subroutes : [
                                    {
                                        pattern : ":all*:",
                                        name : "catchallDetail",
                                        view : "NotFound"
                                    }
                                  ]
                  }
                 ]
    }
},

    init : function() {
    sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

    var mConfig = this.getMetadata().getConfig();

    var rootPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("sap.ui.demo.tdg");

    var i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
        bundleUrl : [rootPath, mConfig.resourceBundle].join("/")
    });
    this.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");

    var sServiceUrl = mConfig.serviceConfig.serviceUrl;
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, true);
    this.setModel(oModel);

    var deviceModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
        isTouch : sap.ui.Device.support.touch,
        isNoTouch : !sap.ui.Device.support.touch,
        isPhone : sap.ui.Device.system.phone,
        isNoPhone : !sap.ui.Device.system.phone,
        listMode : sap.ui.Device.system.phone ? "None" : "SingleSelectMaster",
        listItemType : sap.ui.Device.system.phone ? "Active" : "Inactive"
    });
    deviceModel.setDefaultBindingMode("OneWay");
    this.setModel(deviceModel, "device");

    this.getRouter().initialize();
},

});
```

MyRouter.js

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.routing.RouteMatchedHandler");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.routing.Router");
jQuery.sap.declare("sap.ui.demo.tdg.MyRouter");

sap.ui.core.routing.Router.extend("sap.ui.demo.tdg.MyRouter", {

constructor : function() {
    sap.ui.core.routing.Router.apply(this, arguments);
    this._oRouteMatchedHandler = new sap.m.routing.RouteMatchedHandler(this);
},

myNavBack : function(sRoute, mData) {
    var oHistory = sap.ui.core.routing.History.getInstance();
    var sPreviousHash = oHistory.getReviousHash();

    if(sPreviousHash !== undefined) {
        window.history.go(-1);
    } else {
        var bReplace = true;
        this.navTo(sRoute, mData, bReplace);
    }
},

myNavToWithoutHash : function (oOptions) {
    var oSplitApp = this._findSplitApp(oOptions.currentView);

    var oView = this.getView(oOptions.targetView, oOptions.targetViewType);
    oSplitApp.addPage(oView, oOptions.isMaster);
    oSplitApp.to(oView.geId(), oOptions.transition || "show", oOptions.data);
},

backWithouHash : function (oCurrentView, bIsMaster) {
    var sBackMethod = bIsMaster ? "backMaster" : "backDetail";
    this._findSplitApp(oCurrentView)[sBackMethod]();
},

destroy : function (oControl) {
    sap.ui.core.routing.Router.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
    this._oRouteMatchedHandler.destroy();
},

_findSplitApp : function (oControl) {
    sAncestorControlName = "idAppControl";

    if (oControl instanceof sap.ui.core.mvc.View & oControl.byId(sAncestorControlName)){
        return oControl.byId(sAncestorConrolName);
    }

    return oControl.getParent() ? this._findSplitApp(oControl.getParent(), sAncestorControlName) : null;
}

 });
```

Comment: It's `SplitApp` with capital S. You may want to check your spelling in your App view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a spelling mistake. Thx to Qualiture